# php image uploading into mysql

Tags: php, html

i have this code. My goal is uploading an image into mysql by using php. This gives error:404. I've checked my code again and again but nothing looks wrong. There are anything wrong with the mysqli_connection, i've tried uploading something else and that worked fine, but for image i have a problem, error:404. Anyone has any ideas about what's the problem here?
Note: the current file's name is upload.php

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Resim Yükleyiniz</title>                        //Upload and image
</head>

<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="resim" value="Resim Seçiniz"> <input type="submit" value="Yükle">                        //choose an image , upload
</form>
</body>

<?php
//getting mysqli connection
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql.hostinger.web.tr","*******-user","*****-password") or die(mysql_error());
mysqli_select_db($con,"********-database name") or die(mysql_error());

$ders = $_GET['ders'];

//getting file content
$dosya = $_FILES['resim']['tmp_name'];
if(isset($dosya)){
  $resim = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['resim']['tmp_name']));

  //control of if the file is an image or not
  $resim_boyutu = getimagesize($_FILES['resim']['tmp_name']);                                         //This gives false if the $dosya is not an image
  if($resim_boyutu == false)
    echo "Lütfen resim türünden bir dosya seçiniz.";
  else {
    if(!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO $ders VALUES ('','$resim')"))                  //uploading image into the table
      echo "Görüntü yüklenirken bir hata oluştu.";
    else
      echo "Görüntü yüklendi";
  }
}

else
  echo "Lütfen resim seçiniz.";

?>

</html>
```

Comment: what you got in print_r($_FILES) ? Do you have any reserved characters (eg spaces, punctuation, non-ASCII) characters in the image name?

Comment: Has _mat_upload.php_

Comment: @Ayak973 ah really really thanks!!! i've changed a .php file name but forgot to change the connections to it. I've given much time to solve this argh.. Small bugs..

Comment: @Ayak973 uhm.. I've corrected it but still the error:404 is coming. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Bhavin I got a PNG file in $_FILES

Comment: you need to fix your `die` statement. it's currently a `mysql_` statement so will never give you a useful result

Comment: @Martin oh really.. I forgot it thank you. But i think there is not a problem about connecting to database because in another example without image, connection works well, but thank you i will correct it

Comment: can you show the code where you try and output the image? what exactly gives you a error 404? The image is assumed to be stored in the DB but you need to encapsulate the image as a file to have it displayed by HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image Uploading to mysql database using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26056870/image-uploading-to-mysql-database-using-php)

Comment: @Marcel1997 no problem in that link is not checking if the file is set or not, but i am already checking it

Comment: @Martin i  haven't passed into showing image yet, i've prepared the code but not haven't run it yet. I want to be sure the uploading works correctly first. The error:404 is not coming because of displaying an image it is an issue about uploading and the problem is in this code but idk where exactly.

Comment: ok, I need you to explain in more detail what the error 404 refers to? I can't see what it would refer to except when you submit the form and the destination file (`upload.php`) doesn't exist?

Comment: As @Martin said, we cannot troubleshoot your issue if we didnt know from wich requested file you have a 404 response.
Just a guess : has your web server enough permission to read the file _upload.php_ ?

Answer (score 0):

use [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) or [`exif_imagetype()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php)

```
// integer - for example: IMAGETYPE_GIF, IMAGETYPE_JPEG etc.
$type   = exif_imagetype($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
```

or

```
$info   = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$mime   = $info['mime']; // mime-type as string for ex. "image/jpeg" etc.
$width  = $info[0];      // width as integer for ex. 512
$height = $info[1];      // height as integer for ex. 384
$type   = $info[2];      // same as exif_imagetype
```

Mind that `exif_imagetype` is much faster than `getimagesize.` Check documentation for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Lots to fix here. (I often think I should have signed up to Code Review rather than Stack Overflow)

- you have old mysql_ references in your `die` statement in your code which will never give you a useful response. instead replace with `die(mysqli_error($con))`.
- It is highly recommended to also state database when using `mysqli_connect` rather than as a separate method call. [Read the Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php)
- You really should be checking for file upload Error codes before acting on the $_FILE data. For example: `if($_FILES['resim']['error'] == 0){ process upload }`
- As you are clearly using non-ascii language it is highly recommended to use `accept-charset='utf-8'` in your `<form>` tag.
- I recommend reading about [saving filedata into MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717506/how-to-upload-images-into-mysql-database-using-php-code), and I would also recommend that you don't, it's far better and efficient and easier to debug to simply save a *reference* to a file in the DB and store the image file on the server disc, rather than as a field in a database. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay).
- You need to be extremely careful (read: change, **urgently**!) having a `$_GET` value unqualified and plugged straight into your SQL query: `INSERT INTO $ders` this is a ***really bad idea*** and should not be done. At the very least you should remove any invalid or control characters with a [Preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) Regex, such as:

  ```
   $ders = preg_replace("/[a-z0-9_]/i","",$_GET['ders']);
  ```
- What makes you think you need to `addslashes` to your `file_get_contents`? I would suggest *not* adding slashes, instead escaping the data value with:

  ```
  $resim = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, 
           file_get_contents($_FILES['resim']['tmp_name']));
  ```
- Even better would be to use [MySQLi Prepared Statements](http://www.pontikis.net/blog/dynamically-bind_param-array-mysqli) and combine this with Object Orientated Database Programming. ***This approach comes highly recommended***.

I can't provide you any output debugging/help because you have not (yet) stated what causes your Error 404 which you report in your question. Add this data (edit your question) and let me know and then I can revise this.

**Additional**: Because you're clearly using a non-ascii character set, I would highly recommend spending a bit of time and giving [this Stack Overflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through) a read through, so you know how to approach database character encodings correctly. This could potentially save you *days* of stress. I don't *think* this is an issue with you from the standpoint of this question.

I would also recommend using the [mb_string PHP module](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) for making sure PHP correctly handles multibyte strings correctly.